# adding rows to the datatable using jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, database, html, datatable

I'm trying to add rows to the `datatable` directly by giving values to the `.js` file using metronic theme. But no values are added to the `datatable`.The problem is its not getting reflected on the table.When debugged it,item values are getting displayed but its not getting added to the row array for the table.

```
HTML code:



    <!-- BEGIN MAIN CONTENT -->
                <div class="row" ng-controller="compctrl">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
                        <div class="portlet box blue-hoki">
                            <div class="portlet-title">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Datatable with TableTools
                                </div>
                                <div class="tools">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portlet-body">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id="sample_1">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                strength
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>

                                    </thead>
                                    </table> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->


  .js code:
MetronicApp.controller('compctrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {

    alert("Controller called!");

            var tableData= [{'name':'Infosys Technologies','strength':1000}];

                  var table=$('sample_1').DataTable();

              tableData.forEach(function(item)
              {
                            var row=[];  
                            row.push(item.name); 
                            row.push(item.strength);
                            table.add(row);

               });
            table.draw(row);
                 } );
    }]);
```

Comment: Can you please put a jsFiddle? At first look code seems ok to me, just one mistake I guess `$('sample_1').DataTable();` should be `$('#sample_1').DataTable();`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the issue in Fiddle but can't do it. So I have written a simpler version of it and tested. It is working.

```
    var MetronicApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    MetronicApp.controller('compctrl', function($scope) { 

        alert("Controller called!");

        var tableData= [{'name':'Infosys Technologies','strength':1000}];

        var table=$('#sample_1').DataTable();

        tableData.forEach(function(item)
        {
            var row=[];  
            row.push(item.name); 
            row.push(item.strength);
            table.row.add(row).draw(false);
        });

   });
```

Comment: thanks it worked....

  var tableData= [{'name':'Infosys Technologies','strength':1000}];
            
                  var table=$('#sample_1').DataTable();

              tableData.forEach(function(item)
              {
                            var row=[];  
                            row.push(item.name); 
                            row.push(item.strength);
                            /*rows.add(row);*/
                  table.row.add(row);
               
               });
            
            table.draw();
              
                 } );


    }]);
 this is also working.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you. Could you please mark my solution as answer. It will help others to quickly solve the similar problem.

Comment: I need one more help that when I click on row it should add the duplicate entries to the datatable.

Comment: Its simple, put the code for inserting rows in table (the foreach loop and initialization of datatable) in a function and call that function on click of row.